# jooq 3.12.0 codegen tool strategy class not found

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am having trouble getting the jooq codegen tool to run with my custom JooqCodegenStrategy class. I downloaded jooq 3.12.0 and unzipped it into a directory on my Ubuntu system. In this directory, I have the following files.

```
jooq-3.12.0.jar
jooq-checker-3.12.0.jar
jooq-codegen-3.12.0.jar
jooq-codegen-maven-3.12.0.jar
JooqCodegenStrategy.class
JooqCodegenStrategy.java
jooq-meta-3.12.0.jar
jooq-meta-extensions-3.12.0.jar
jooq-scala_2.12-3.12.0.jar
jooq_sd3.jar
jooq.xml
mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar*
reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar
```

I can successfully run the code generation tool when I do not have the following (below) in my jooq.xml.

```
<generator>
  <strategy>
    <name>com.simpletest.JooqCodegenStrategy</name>
  </strategy>
</generator>
```

In order to build the JooqCodegenStrategy class, from terminal, I compile this Java file using:

```
javac -classpath jooq-meta-3.12.0.jar:jooq-codegen-3.12.0.jar JooqCodegenStrategy.java
```

That appears to work and it creates the JooqCodegenStrategy.class file. I package that file into a jar so I can reference it on the classpath when running the codegen tool. I create the jar file using:

```
jar -cvf jooq_sd3.jar JooqCodegenStrategy.class
```

At this point, I believe I have what I need to run the codegen tool. I run the codegen tool using this:

```
java -classpath jooq-3.12.0.jar:jooq-meta-3.12.0.jar:jooq-codegen-3.12.0.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar:reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:jooq_sd3.jar:. org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool /jooq.xml
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
Aug 30, 2019 4:44:12 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Initialising properties  : /jooq.xml
Aug 30, 2019 4:44:13 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
SEVERE: Cannot read /jooq.xml. Error : com.simpletest.JooqCodegenStrategy
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simpletest.JooqCodegenStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass0(GenerationTool.java:925)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass(GenerationTool.java:869)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0(GenerationTool.java:380)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:221)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:216)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:188)
```

My jooq.xml file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
    <jdbc>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sd3?useSSL=false</url>
        <user>myuser</user>
        <password>mypass</password>
    </jdbc>

    <generator>
        <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
        <strategy>
            <name>com.simpletest.JooqCodegenStrategy</name>
        </strategy>

        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
            <inputSchema>sd3</inputSchema>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes>sometableshere</excludes>
            <forcedTypes>
                <forcedType>
                    <name>JsonElement</name>
                    <expression>board_data</expression>
                    <types>JSON</types>
                </forcedType>
            </forcedTypes>
        </database>

        <target>
            <packageName>model.data</packageName>
            <directory>./src/main/java/com/simpletest/domain/</directory>
        </target>

        <generate>
            <relations>true</relations>
            <deprecated>true</deprecated>
            <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
            <generatedAnnotation>true</generatedAnnotation>
            <records>true</records>
            <pojos>true</pojos>
            <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
            <interfaces>false</interfaces>
            <daos>true</daos>
            <jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>
            <validationAnnotations>false</validationAnnotations>
            <springAnnotations>true</springAnnotations>
            <globalObjectReferences>true</globalObjectReferences>
            <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
        </generate>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compiling your Java class in the local directory works, that means that your class doesn't have a package (i.e. it is in the default package). Which means your qualification of that class is wrong:

```
<generator>
  <strategy>
    <name>com.simpletest.JooqCodegenStrategy</name>
  </strategy>
</generator>
```

It is not in the `com.simpletest` package. The use of the default package is generally discouraged in Java. In many cases (e.g. in this one too, I think), you will not be able to load the class from a random position.

Better add the package declaration to your class:

```
package com.simpletest;
```

And move the class in a `com/simpletest` subdirectory.

Comment: This worked for me. I want to keep my JooqCodegenStrategy separate from my primary project source, but still within the repo. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mule: In maven, you'd be defining a separate module in your project for this. Gradle would work in a similar way... That way, the code generation could be automated, even if you update that strategy class.